# More concise forms generate list with elements 0 and 1

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I need to generate all such lists, it consists of 14 1's and 4 0's, there should be at least 3 1's between two adjacent 0's. I came up with a pattern matching approach, it's a bit long.

```
perms = Permutations[Table[If[i <= 4, 0, 1], {i, 18}]];

ans = Cases[perms, {___, 0, ___, 1, 1, 1, ___, 0, ___, 1, 1, 1, ___, 0, ___, 1, 1, 1, ___, 0, ___}];

Length[ans]
```

Is there an concise way? It's not necessarily based on pattern matching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** An alternative approach to construct  the restricted permutations directly (rather than filtering all permutations):

```
permutationsOfIntegerPartitions = 
  Join @@ Map[Permutations] @ IntegerPartitions[#, {#2}, Range[#3, #]] &;

toBinaryPermutations = Splice @* 
  MapApply[Flatten @ Riffle[Map[ConstantArray[1, #] &] @ #, 0] & @ 
   {#2[[1]], Splice @ #, #2[[2]]} &] @* Tuples;

binaryNecklaces[b_ : 14, w_ : 4, distance_ : 3] := 
 If[b < distance   (w - 1), {}, 
  Table[toBinaryPermutations @ 
    {permutationsOfIntegerPartitions[b - i, w - 1, distance], 
     permutationsOfIntegerPartitions[i, 2, 0]},
   {i, 0, b - distance  (w - 1)}]]
```

***Examples:***

```
Sort @ binaryNecklaces[] == ans
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
MatrixPlot[Transpose @ binaryNecklaces[], 
  ImageSize -> 1 -> 8, Mesh -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

```
MatrixPlot[Transpose @ binaryNecklaces[12, 4, 3],
  ImageSize -> 1 -> 15, Mesh -> All, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

```
MatrixPlot[Transpose @ binaryNecklases[13, 4, 4], 
   ImageSize -> 1 -> 15, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ans2 = DeleteCases[{___, 0, Repeated[1, {0, 2}], 0, ___}] @ perms;

ans3 = Cases[Except[{___, 0, Repeated[1, {0, 2}], 0, ___}]] @ perms

ans == ans2 == ans3
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Very nice! If I add another condition, the list starts and ends with 1, do I need twice `Cases`?

Comment: maybe `Cases[Except[{___, 0, Repeated[1, {0, 2}], 0, ___} | {0, __} | {__, 0}]]@perms`?

Comment: .. or `DeleteCases[{___, 0, Repeated[1, {0, 2}], 0, ___} | {0, __} | {__,    0}]@perms`

Comment: It works! Thank you very much.

Comment: @vector, my pleasure. Welcome to mmase.